# This c# code displays the first letter decimal value of a string only...e.g the output is ..101.. when it should display ... 101 032 057 097 065

Tags: c#, string, byte

Blockquote

i wanted the code to convert user input 'plaintext' to ascii decimal values of each character in the plaintext and display it in a textbox in the form 101 095 095 032 but instead it displayed the ascii decimal value of the first character of the plaintext only.

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Drawing;
     using System.Windows.Forms;
     using System.IO; 

     namespace encrypto
      {
      public partial class MainForm : Form
      {
     public MainForm()
      {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string  Plaintext = textBox1.Text;
     byte CipherText;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) {
         MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Text To Be Hidden.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,    MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    }

     for(int i=0; i < Plaintext.Length;i++)
    {
        CipherText = (byte)Plaintext[i];
        textBox3.Text = string.Format ("{0}",CipherText);                   
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Can you post the real code? This doesn't compile or come close to being valid code.

Comment: Your for loop is overwriting CipherText on each iteration, you would need to append to a string value each iteration the value of CipherText then set textBox3.Text = the string value after the for loop.

Comment: @RonBeyer okay done

Comment: @RyanWilson could you please help me with that,,like show me the code to do that,,im kinda new to c#

Comment: @TroyE Adding an answer below that should do what you need, one moment.

Comment: @TroyE Answered, let me know if that helps and solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a string value and append to it on each iteration, then set the textbox.text property value.

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Drawing;
     using System.Windows.Forms;
     using System.IO; 

     namespace encrypto
     {
       public partial class MainForm : Form
       {
         public MainForm()
         {

            InitializeComponent();

         }

    void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string  Plaintext = textBox1.Text;
        string byteText = "";
        byte CipherText;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Text To Be Hidden.", "Error", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,    MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        }

        for(int i=0; i < Plaintext.Length;i++)
        {
           CipherText = (byte)Plaintext[i];
           byteText += System.Convert.ToString(CipherText) + " ";     //+= appends text to the string          
        }
           textBox3.Text = string.Format ("{0}",byteText);    //Now that we have all byte text in our string, place it into the textbox.Text property as value
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried it and it solved my problem

Comment: @TroyE Cool. Glad I could help, please mark my answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: okay ive done that.

Comment: @TroyE Thank you.